# UIImagePickerController - On Camera Finished Closing (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimagepickercontroller

I've just finished dealing with a large handful of bugs, but there's one that's proving a little difficult to squish. I know *exactly* why the bug is happening, and it's exceedingly easy to fix, I just need an event that is triggered immediately after the camera menu closes (brought up by a UIImagePickerController). Any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`UIImagePickerController` has two callbacks, as defined in the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`:

```
imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)
imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_:)
```

See the docs for more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/)

Also, remember to set a delegate for the image picker before showing it!